# Can not connect to AWS parse server on Mac : ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services

[The image from my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WX7m.png)

Hi, I am following a Swift Xcode class, and now we are building a project required to connect with AWS parse server, After tried lots of times, it still the same error: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Here is the error message:

luodeMacBook-Air:desktop luo$ chmod 400 onepicioskeypair.pem luodeMacBook-Air:desktop luo$ ssh -i "onepicioskeypair.pem" ubuntu@ec2-18-216-187-86.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out luodeMacBook-Air:desktop luo$

Answer (score 0):

Please verify you are trying with correct ip address or url.

change EC2 setting to Allow all IP address 
and restart instance and try again

Comment: Thank you so much! do you know exactly where I can change EC2 setting on AWS?